# console output stating bit length overflow

Tags: iphone, overflow, bit

When I run my app I get this output to the console:

bit length overflow
code 11 bits 7->5
code 16 bits 4->5

bit length overflow
code 4 bits 6->7

bit length overflow
code 3 bits 6->7
code 0 bits 6->7

bit length overflow
code 16 bits 4->5

bit length overflow
code 4 bits 6->7
code 5 bits 6->5
code 16 bits 4->5

bit length overflow
code 16 bits 4->5

bit length overflow
code 0 bits 6->7

bit length overflow
code 11 bits 6->7

The app zips up 3 files and saves it to its documents folder and all seems OK....apart from this output.

**UPDATED:**

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init]; 

@try { 
    NSString *docsPath =[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
    NSString *filePath = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ZipTest.zip"]; 
    ZipFile *zipFile = [[ZipFile alloc] initWithFileName:filePath mode:ZipFileModeCreate]; 
    ZipWriteStream *stream; 

    if (self.textSwitch.on) { 
        stream = [zipFile writeFileInZipWithName:@"text.txt" compressionLevel:ZipCompressionLevelBest];
    } 
    [zipFile close]; 
    [zipFile release]; 
} 
@catch (ZipException *ze) {} 
@catch (id e) {} 

[pool drain];
```

What does it mean?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide more context?  Maybe share some code that leads to this output?

Comment: NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
@try {        
NSString *docsPath =[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSString *filePath = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ZipTest.zip"];
ZipFile *zipFile = [[ZipFile alloc] initWithFileName:filePath mode:ZipFileModeCreate];
ZipWriteStream *stream;
if (self.textSwitch.on) {
stream = [zipFile writeFileInZipWithName:@"text.txt" compressionLevel:ZipCompressionLevelBest];
}
[zipFile close];
zipFile release];
} @catch (ZipException *ze) {} 
@catch (id e) {}
[pool drain];

Comment: never have figured out how to add proper code blocks here...sorry

Comment: i am also having this problem . any body has some idea that how i can resolve it ... i am getting this logs while zipping sqlite file.

Answer (score 2):

According to this [Mozilla bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=448733)these are caused by building ZLIB in debug mode and are harmless.. You could look into always building a release version of ZLIB.